# How can I get the just hour value from current time ( not date ) from Device, Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to an extension for just get the current hour from Device with an Objective-C code.
For example: `12.30.48` output `12`
Thanks

Comment: Have a look at ```NSDateComponents```.

Comment: ... and `NSCalendar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour) fromDate:date];
NSInteger hour = [components hour];
```

Comment: I did not downvote but I want to ... won't work and also is like cutting butter with a chainsaw ... it will work but it will be messy ... first you create a formatter, then use that to convert to string, then convert the string to a date then you get the hour from that date. Not that [date hour] is legal anyhow, but it much too much overkill for a simple thing ...

Comment: ... but don't stop, we need all the help we can get ...

Comment: @skaak refactored my codes and i think this time i used a knife for cutting the butter :)

Comment: Nice I'll bring jam and toast ... nice thanks